# Spring 3 NPE with LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy autoCommit

Tags: spring

I'm using Spring 3 with JPA and I'm seeing an intermittent issue in my web application. 
I have wrapper for the JPA EntityManager that calls the underlying EntityManager crud methods.  I see a NPE sometimes when I call `entityManager.persist(object);` It looks the the database connection is lost but I'm not 100% what is the cause.  Anyone have any details on what may have caused the below exception?

Spring Version: 3.0.6.RELEASE

**Spring 3 LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java line 416:**

```
if (this.autoCommit != null && this.autoCommit != this.target.getAutoCommit()) {
    this.target.setAutoCommit(this.autoCommit);
}
```

**Exception:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocationHandler.getTargetConnection(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:416)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:376)
        at $Proxy64.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:534)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareSelectStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:145)
        at org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator.generate(SequenceGenerator.java:96)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:122)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:49)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:154)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:110)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:61)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:646)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:620)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:624)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:220)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor101.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
        at $Proxy79.persist(Unknown Source)
        at myapp.api.dao.impl.GenericDAOImpl.save(GenericDAOImpl.java:50)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor100.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at $Proxy119.save(Unknown Source)
        at myapp.api.service.impl.backoffice.StoringServiceImpl.store(StoringServiceImpl.java:89)
        at myapp.api.service.impl.backoffice.StoringServiceImpl.storeIncludedFeatureMessage(StoringServiceImpl.java:68)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor124.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at $Proxy168.storeIncludedFeatureMessage(Unknown Source)
        at myapp.api.listener.backoffice.StorableMessageListener.processNew(StorableMessageListener.java:136)
        at myapp.api.listener.backoffice.StorableMessageListener.onMessage(StorableMessageListener.java:187)
        ... 34 more
```

**Spring Configuration:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:hz="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring
        http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring/hazelcast-spring-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

        <!-- Generic -->
        <context:annotation-config />
        <context:component-scan base-package="myapp.api" />
        <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

        <!-- JPA -->
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

        <tx:annotation-driven />

        <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

        <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
            <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="MyApp" />
            <property name="jpaProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.archive.autodetection">class</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">com.hazelcast.hibernate.provider.HazelcastCacheProvider</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts">true</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>


       <hz:hazelcast id="instance">
            <hz:config>
                 //rest of Hazelast config here
            </hz:config>
        </hz:hazelcast>

        <hz:hibernate-region-factory id="regionFactory" instance-ref="instance"/>

        <!-- Define JPA Provider Adapter -->
        <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="dataSourceTarget" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" destroy-method="close">
            <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:1525:name" />
            <property name="user" value="test" />
            <property name="password" value="123" />
            <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true" />
            <property name="connectionCacheProperties">
                <props merge="default">
                    <prop key="MinLimit">5</prop>
                    <prop key="MaxLimit">50</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy">
            <property name="targetDataSource" ref="dataSourceTarget"/>
        </bean>


        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
            <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        </bean>

        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="false"/>

        <bean id="genericDAO" class="myapp.api.dao.impl.GenericDAOImpl">
            <constructor-arg>
                <value>java.io.Serializable</value>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>

        <bean id="springContextHolder" class="myapp.api.util.SpringContextHolder" factory-method="getInstance" />

<bean id="executionInterceptor" class="myapp.api.listener.backoffice.ExecutionInterceptor" />

        </beans>
```

**AOP Error Handler:**

```
package myapp.api.listener.backoffice;


import javax.jms.Message;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.util.StopWatch;

@Aspect
public class ExecutionInterceptor extends BaseListener{
    //protected Log log = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());
    private String errorDestination="ErrorQ";
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("jmsTemplate")
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Around("execution(* onMessage(javax.jms.Message))")
    public Object aroundOnMessage(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable{
        StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
        stopWatch.start();  
        Object retVal = pjp.proceed();  
        stopWatch.stop();  
        log.trace( pjp.getSignature().getName() + " Execution Time: " + stopWatch.getTotalTimeMillis()+" ms" );
        return retVal;
    }
    @AfterReturning("execution(* onMessage(javax.jms.Message))")
    public void afterOnMessage(){
        // logic to capture time
        log.debug("*****************************EXIT ONMESSAGE*******************************");

    }

    @Around("execution(* commit(..))")
    public Object aroundCommit(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable{
        try{
            return pjp.proceed();
        }catch(Throwable ex){
            log.error( "Unexpected Error occured during database commit routing message to ErrorQ", ex);
            jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(errorDestination, ex);
            throw ex;
        }finally{
            log.trace( "Commiting Transaction...");
        }

    }
    @AfterThrowing(value="execution(* onMessage(javax.jms.Message) throws java.lang.RuntimeException)",throwing="ex")
    public void afterThrowingOnMessage(JoinPoint jp,RuntimeException ex) throws RuntimeException{
        log.trace("Unexpected Error occured during onMessage processing routing to ErrorQ");
        log.error("{{ERROR}}", ex);
        Object[] args = jp.getArgs();
        if (args!=null && args[0] instanceof javax.jms.Message){
            Message msg = (Message)args[0];
            jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(errorDestination, msg);
            log.info("Unexpected Error occured successfully routed to ErrorQ");
        }else
            log.info("Unexpected Error occured failed to route to ErrorQ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Which exact spring version are you using?

Comment: @tstorms 3.0.6.RELEASE

Comment: Have you considered using the latest spring version? Right now it's 3.2.2.RELEASE. This way, we rule out possible fixed bugs.

Comment: I could attempt that, but this is a production issue and an upgrade would mean an upgrade to all web applications using this common jar.  This was never encountered for the past year in production when using 3.0.6.

Comment: Is it an option to use your dataSourceTarget bean directly instead of the dataSource bean?

Comment: I could attempt that, yes.  What is your thinking behind moving it?

Comment: I'd just like to see whether this issue is related to the LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy class. By using the OracleDataSource directly in the entityManagerFactory you disable the laziness.

Comment: great suggestion, I'll attempt this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the NPE is thrown because the connection is null (variable this.target).

The connection is obtained from the DataSource a few lines before (LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java):

```
// Fetch physical Connection from DataSource.
this.target = (this.username != null) ? getTargetDataSource().getConnection(this.username, this.password) : getTargetDataSource().getConnection();
```

Googling I have found that Oracle JDBC driver may return a null connection in the following situation ([link](https://kr.forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1322557)):

> ConnectionWaitTimeout
>
> Specifies cache behavior when a connection is requested and there are
>   already MaxLimit connections active. If ConnectionWaitTimeout is
>   greater than zero, then each connection request waits for the
>   specified number of seconds or until a connection is returned to the
>   cache. If no connection is returned to the cache before the timeout
>   elapses, then the connection request returns null.
>
> Default: 0 (no timeout)

So, I guess, a connection timeout could explain your inconsistent problem.

Comment: I'm going to try to increase ConnectionWaitTimeout to 30 seconds, unless you have another recommendation for the timeout value?  I may also raise the MaxLimit from 50 to 75.

Comment: Changing those parameters should reduce the number of timeouts, but you should still handle the exceptions in your application code (eg. retry, show message to user... depends on your application).

Comment: The exception is handled as we put the message in an error queue that can then be reprocessed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you got your transactions applied correctly ?

Can you show the conifg files for datasource ?

Also it look slike you are using AOP with these files 
at

```
myapp.api.listener.backoffice.StorableMessageListener.processNew(StorableMessageListener.java:136)

myapp.api.listener.backoffice.StorableMessageListener.onMessage(StorableMessageListener.java:187)
```

Comment: I've posted my Spring Configuration.  This same configuration was working for the past year in our production environment and nothing has changed with respect to the configuration.  It could be at the network or database level, but unfortunately I can't dig into those areas much.  Any ideas on how to view active connections, maybe I've hit my max allowed by Glassfish.  Any ideas why Spring would throw that Exception?

Comment: What does the code in StorableMessageListener do ? That looks like its firing thanks to some AOP ...

Comment: Its a Spring JMS listener that is processing messages from a OpenMQ message queue and storing them in a Oracle database.

Comment: that looks like where the null reference is

Comment: I added the code for the AOP based bean ExecutionInterceptor.  The purpose of ExecutionInterceptor is to route a message to the ErrorQ (queue to hold messages that throw Exceptions)

Comment: thats not *StorableMessageListener.onMessage* though, which is what the stacktrace points at

Comment: So StorableMessageListener.onMessage calls StorableMessageListener.processNew(StorableMessageListener.java:136) which then calls storingService.storeIncludedFeatureMessage.  storingService is a Spring autowired service (class uses the @Service).  The storingService then calls a Spring autowired DAO to make the insert to the DB

Comment: the dao has the reference to the datasource that is not being configured correctly. Can you run in debug mode, and check th elogs for errant messages

Comment: the DAO extends my GenericDAOImpl which has a @PersistenceContext EntityManager entityManager; reference. So the DAO calls entityManager.persist(object);

Comment: The personistencecontext is not being injected correctly when called from that source then.

Comment: For example, the web app works fine for 4 days and then for 5 minutes, we'll get a lot of the LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy Exceptions, our ErrorQ will fill up with messages, but then everything is fine. This has happened three times so far.  Just giving you all the info I have...

Comment: under heavy load ? Or any other factor that causes it ?

Comment: add an example above.  The load did seem a bit high in most cases.